# What's the effect of parallel resistor and MOV?

Tags: resistors, mov

What is the effect of connecting a metal oxide varistor in parallel with a resistor? Does the resistor make the varistor more responsive in case of a surge?

Comment: Can you please share your source of that information?  In my experience there is generally no resistor in parallel with the MOV.

Comment: @jwh20 I don't have a source, per se. It's just a thought experiment.

Comment: Can you give any explanation as to why it would make the varistor more responsive? I can't think of one.

Comment: Have you seen this in an existing circuit? You may add a schematic or describe the module you found this in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will degrade the performance of the MOV. Normally you want the MOV to leak minimal current under normal operating conditions and conduct massive current, if necessary, if an overvoltage appears. Adding the resistor just makes it look like a leaky MOV. The below graph is log-log- the current varies from < 1uA to >10,000A. Graph from [Littelfuse](https://www.littelfuse.com/%7E/media/electronics/trainings/littelfuse_varistor_mov_products_training.pdf.pdf)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The resistor would have no real effect on the MOV and is a waste of a perfectly good resistor.

Here's why:

The purpose of the MOV, which is in effect a VOLTAGE VARIABLE RESISTOR.  That means that as the voltage across it increases the resistance decreases.  Obviously the effect will be to shunt high voltages while doing effectively nothing at lower voltages.

By placing a resistor in parallel with it, that R will simply conduct anytime there is any voltage on the input of the circuit.  In the case of a transient spike, the MOV will conduct with an effective LOW resistance.  So while some current from the spike will flow in the R, it will be minimal because the effective resistance of the MOV is going to be much much lower than the resistor you have place.